# Rearrange lines to tabular format

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to grab the part after "*-*" and combine it with the following letter-string into a tab-output.  I tried something like `cut -d "*-" -f 2 <<< "$your_str"` but I am not sure how to do the whole shuffling.

Input:

```
>1-395652
TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTGT
>2-369990
TATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTCC
>3-132234
TATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTC
>4-122014
TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTGTAA
>5-118616
```

Output:

```
TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTGT 395652
TATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTCC 369990
```

Comment: What criteria are you using to select which lines to output? What should the output be for the final input line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F- '/^>/{k=$2; next} {print $0, k}' file
```

Comment: is this tabular output?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -nE 'N;s/.*-([0-9]+)\n(.*)/\2\t\1/p' file
```

Output:

```
TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTGT  395652
TATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTCC  369990
TATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTC   132234
TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTGTAA        122014
```

Answer (score 1):

Portable `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*-//;x;n;G;s/\n/ /p' inputfile
```

Output:

```
TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTGT 395652
TATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTCC 369990
TATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTC 132234
TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTGTAA 122014
```